# Bulk image editing using existing file name

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm looking for a way to bulk edit .jpeg files and retain their original names. Before you say, "Duh, they already have their original names.", I also want to be able to place that name on the .jpeg as a caption in a location of my choosing. The operative word is bulk. Doing it one file at a time is prohibitive unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Bridge and Adobe Photoshop to do these stuff.

First open Adobe Bridge:

1) All you need select all image files and Go to **Tools > Photoshops > Load Files into Photoshop Layers**
2) Jpeg files will load into Photoshop 
3) I think you've to caption the images manually, I don't have any suggestion for it.
4) After you finished editing then Go to **File > Scripts > Export Layers to Files** 
5) In the Export layers to Files dialog box select **File Type** as Jpeg and select your destination where to save your edited Jpeg files in **Destination** field
6) Now hit **Run** button

Now you'll able to see your edited files. I use this method when I have to do bulk image editing.

Thank you,

Comment: Thanks for the input, but the whole object is to automatically caption the jpegs using the original file name minus the .jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

### Use [XnConvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/) to bulk add a custom caption

- Input: Add files > Select all your images > Open
- Actions: Add action > Image > Text

  - Click on the small arrow > Filename without extension
  - Modify *X margin* and *Y margin* to your needs
- Output:

  - Select *Source folder* as output folder
  - Set `{Filename}` as filename
  - Select *As original* as format
  - Check *Keep original date/time attributes*
  - Check *Preserve Metadata*
- Click *Convert*

[image]